# How does the earphone cable in a mobile phone pick up the FM reception?

Tags: aliasing, frequency-modulation

As I understand, the RF frequency-modulated signal centered in the range of $88-108\textrm{ MHz}$, is picked by the earphone antenna and is directly sampled by the sound card adc at $48\textrm{ kHz}$ and then digitally processed. Will this process not cause aliasing? Could anyone please correct my understanding?

Comment: Your question is based on a misunderstanding. The RF signal is *not* directly sampled by the sound card.

Comment: by the way, capitalization *makes* a difference. m = milli = $10^{-3}$; M = Mega = $10^6$. Also, Hertz is abbreviated Hz, not hz.

Comment: (the earphone cable just doubles as an antenna for a dedicated FM receiver; the soundcard hasn't got anything to do with FM reception. In fact, it doesn't even "get" radio frequencies – they're filtered out before and fed to the FM receive chain)

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is a fine answer, why not post below so this one is not left open? I fixed the title.

Comment: @DanBoschen If you say so :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding. The RF signal is *not* directly sampled by the sound card.

Instead, the earphone cable just doubles as an antenna for a dedicated FM receiver; the soundcard hasn't got anything to do with FM reception.
In fact, it doesn't even "get" radio frequencies – they're filtered out before and fed to the FM receive chain.

Comment: @DanBoschen Antenna design was never that easy :-) Just grasp a pair of earphone cables, lay it over somewhere and connect to your FM receiver front end. Now I really wonder how can that **shapeless** thing can even **help** in FM reception? It seems there's a high probability of achieving a **flat** piece of 15 cms along the cable, or it seems there is not even such a requirement on the antenna design, which returns to my inital statement therefore

Comment: well, they're certainly crappy antennas. But: compared to the demands of cellular data, the requirements of FM radio are very benign, so I guess even with an extremely bad antenna efficiency, when you've got the technology to receive 3G / 4G, you'll do well enough. I also guess that for ~100 MHz signals (which isn't all that far from the baseband bandwidth of 4G), on-chip adjustable matching networks

Comment: well in my mind was the picture of an old sony walkman indeed, but probably the same would apply for 4G reception as well.

Comment: @Fat32 : AM antennas in pocket radios are even more tiny and shapeless, and have no problem gathering enough EM.  As long as the antenna gathers less noise than broadcast RF, a reasonable S/N signal can be amplified with an LNA.

Comment: @hotpaw2 well, most small antennas are magnetic  antennas, essentially coils wound around a ferrite core; they're pretty high-resonance (high-Q).

Comment: @hotpaw2 ok I admit! I'm a little weak in antennas... too bad. But as Marcus has pointed, old classical AM antennas are coils wound around ferromagnetic cores which amplify the externally imposed magnetic field by several hundreds (if not thousands) of times... As a result $\lambda/4$ does not apply there :-)